# Java Buffered reader running out of heap space

Tags: java, string, xml-parsing, bufferedreader

I'm trying to parse a very large file (~1.2 GB). Some lines of the file are bigger than the maximum allowed String size.

```
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
              //Do something
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:569)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:369)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:370)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at sax.parser.PrettyPrintXML.format(PrettyPrintXML.java:30)
```

line 30 :

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
```

Can anyone suggest any alternative approach for this case.

Comment: @Reimeus None of the answers can satisfy my case. I cannot read byte block. I need to append them at some time and after I append it will show an error

Comment: How about increasing the available heap space (setting `-Xmx`)?

Comment: @KErlandsson I guess that increases the heap size but not string size. can you rewrite the above code such that it uses heap space instead of string

Comment: If you have a very long line e.g. you have 1.2 GB wihout new lines, you need enough memory to load the entire line at once. (as the buffer grows dynamically you need roughtly 2x and since you have char not bytes in a String you need 2x that) In short you need at least 5 GB of memory free worst case.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have free memory my machine's memory is 16GB, but I'm not able to avoid the error even after using `-Xmx`

Comment: @LeDerp I assume your program is doing more than just reading the XML, is it possible you are using memory but the error is only showing up when you read more data.  Have you used a memory profiler to see how it is used.

Comment: I deleted rest of my code and tried to run it again, It's still showing the same error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `readLine()` on a file that doesn't have lines. So it tries to read the entire file as a single lines. This does not scale.

Solution: don't. Read a chunk at a time, or maybe even a character at a time: whatever is dictated by the unstated structure of your file.

Comment: This works, used `read()` method instead of `readline()` . Now I read a character at a time and append them later.

Comment: You can use Apache IOUtils also.

Comment: @AliHelmy Use them why? There's nothing there that magically solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe maximum string character length is 2^31-1 [2,147,483,647] and 1.2GB txt file(assuming is a txt file) can store about 1,200,000,000 characters. Why do you need to read all the data? What are you using it for? Can you split the file up into several files or read and parse it as a smaller string. Need more info.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Apache commons IO :

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/description.html

example:

```
 InputStream in = new URL( "http://commons.apache.org" ).openStream();
 try {
   System.out.println( IOUtils.toString( in ) );
 } finally {
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
 }
```

Comment: This would cause exactly the same problem.